# Calculate score of user data in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm looking to generate a score similar to Klout the Klout. But this score will score a user based on their risk for information security theft. We will be using the Facebook API  to get the users data. The score will start from 100 and we will subtract based on the fb data that is present.

(if the following data is available then we subtract 5 points each)

```
user_birthday
user_hometown
user_location
user_relationship_details
user_education_history
user_work_history
user_about_me
user_checkins
```

So far I have this:

```
@fb_data = {:name => 'user_name', :bday => 'user_bday', :about_me => 'user_about_me' }



def calculate

@fb_data.each do |x, y|
  if y != nil
    puts -5
  end



calculate(name: "John", bday: "may 1st", about_me: "hello") 

end
```

Comment: Does this look right, and how can I get the final score.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks. But for some reason Its not working for me in IRB

Comment: @ObedEugene Define "not working". It's not clear what the question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def calculate(data)
  100 - (data.values_at(*@fb_data.keys).compact.length * 5)
end

calculate(name: 'Foo', some_other_key: 'Bar', about_me: 'Baz', bday: nil)
# => 90
```

Comment: No prob. Feel free to upvote my question :)